# Add custom property to 97/2003 MSOffice Files (xls/doc/ppt) using DSOFile 2.1

Tags: ms-office, custom-tags, customproperty, dsofile

I'm trying to add custom property on the ppt file. But Received value("güsiöçÇÖISÜG") is not equal sent value("ğüşiöçÇÖİŞÜĞ").

[image]

I faced a strange situation like that:

- Open the sample.ppt by LibreOffice.
- Save (CTRL+S) and Close, any change is not necessarily.
- Run the code again.
- And two values are equal

Sample ppt files is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qTlREuLAAM-I0JIn-htPwLEUwRjQ9IiJ?usp=sharing

Is there anyone to help me, thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900474/set-windows-file-properties-of-non-office-files

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev thanks for the answer but I can't understand cleary... Is this encoding inconsistentcy about DSOFile or NTFS or DOC(2005) ? Some characters are allowed ( üöçÜÖÇ ) and some characters are not allowed ( ğşıĞŞİ ). Should I change somewhere of code, if yes, where is ?

Comment: Check whether you deal with UTF-8 or UTF-16 encodings.

Comment: Hi, I didn't set an encoding.

Comment: You did not. But the software you use could do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check encodings of your Excel files. Most probably a software (DSO) generates a UTF-8 based document instead of UTF-16. For example, you may try using the following code:

```
Dim strEncodingName As String = String.Empty
Dim myStreamRdr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(myFileName, True)
Dim myString As String = myStreamRdr.ReadToEnd()
strEncodingName = mmFileIA.CurrentEncoding.EncodingName
```